# Recommended way to store chat history for a webapp

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

I'm implementing a web based chat client using Openfire API with Java.

Things are setup and running smoothly, however, I'm a little confused as to where to store chat history.

From what I've observed, Desktop based clients typically store chat history on the client side filesystem using formats such as xml, txt etc.

On the server side, I have the following options:

1. Using plain text file
2. Using json (mongodb, hbase etc)
3. Using database

But I would like to know which is the best of the above options (or any other ones if you can suggest) in terms of speed and performance.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't Openfire already have the ability to store chat logs for all talks?

Comment: No, from what I've observed, all the chat logs are stored on the client side (I've tried it with Spark client and chat history is stored on the client side)

Comment: Just found http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html#pref and https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/monitoring/readme.html

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in isnot2bad's comment, you can add server-side message archiving through the use of the Openfire Monitoring Plugin. Once you have that setup you can try using the XEP-0126 to fetch archived 1-to-1 chat messages over XMPP.

[Openfire Plugins](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp)

Unfortunately I have had nothing but trouble when trying to get messages out of the archive using the stanza's defined in XEP-0136. If you look around the OF support forum you will find other people are also running into problems with this plugin. For example, the plugin will not return the list of conversations in correct order, it will not filter the list of conversations or messages by the date specified by the start attribute, etc. To say the least, the plugin could use some work. As a work around, I've left the plugin in place to take care of inserting the messages into the database, but I've written a custom AJAX solution for the retrieval of the archived messages. I just pull them directly out of OF's database and return them in a JSON object to my client side javascript.

[XEP-0136](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html) is due for replacement, it's always been overly complicated. [XEP-0313](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html) seeks to replace it, but I haven't found any implementations for OF. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @fpsColton, I seem to think that inserting the messages in to the database is a costly operation (unless done in batches which has it's own problems), I would side on using NoSQL (Mongo most likely), thanks anyway...i guess it would be best to develop a custom plugin to serve the business needs...

Comment: @VishwasShashidhar, FYI the current plugin seems to batch insert messages by default. A quick test of my system shows that messages are not archived as they're sent, but rather on an interval of once per minute or so. Even still, it's not a bad idea to avoid the use of this plugin. I've read comments which mention that this plugin was designed more for administrative auditing purposes. Apparently it wasn't really designed to be used for message retrieval from clients.